# How to add OpenMP for loop by replacing the while loop of a sequential code

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, parallel-processing, openmp

the following code is written sequentially. I want to implement OpenMP by replacing while loop to for loop but have no idea how to do this. I know the OpenMP syntax but unable to implement.

The reason to do parallelism is to check the performance between sequential and parallel technique. Any help?

```
  void block::mine_block(uint32_t difficulty) noexcept
{
    string str(difficulty, '0');

    auto start = system_clock::now();

    while (_hash.substr(0, difficulty) != str)
    {
        ++_nonce;
        _hash = calculate_hash();
    }

    auto end = system_clock::now();
    duration<double> diff = end - start;

    cout << "Block mined: " << _hash << " in " << diff.count() << " seconds" << endl;
}
```

**@Matthieu Brucher** **- Can this will be solution?**

```
#pragma omp parallel    // start the parallel region
{
    #pragma omp single  // let the while loop execute by one thread and generate tasks
    while (time < TotalTime){

        #pragma omp task
        {
            // this code will be a task that may be executed immediately on a different core or deferred for later execution
        }

    } // end of while loop and single region
    // at this point we also wait until all tasks that were created have finished

} // end of parallel region
```

**By implementing the above code**

```
#pragma omp parallel                        
    {
        #pragma omp single                      
        while (_hash.substr(0, difficulty) != str) {
            #pragma omp task                    
            {
                ++_nonce;
                _hash = calculate_hash();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I *could* guess what `calculate_hash` does and how `_nonce` is used, but I'd rather base an answer on facts. Please include at least some information about that. Avoid using global variables and instead formulate side-effect free functions. Makes parallelization much easier.

Comment: may i provide the whole code?

Comment: How can you guarantee that `block::mine_block` won't throw? The construction of `str` may throw since it allocates memory (if stored string is not short).

Comment: Generally, if the effect of each iteration depends on previous iteration(s), then such a loop cannot be parallelized.

Comment: The *whole* code is not always desirable if it is long. Usually you should work on a [mcve]. The most important thing we need to know is whether `calculate_hash` has any side-effects and uses any global data. Again, assuming it does access the global variable `_nonce`, you should first refactor it to take it as a parameter before attempting parallelization.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have a dependency in your loop. As such, it is not possible to parallelize it as it is.

A good first approach is to use multiple start points and use several threads that will create new hashes. Then when one of the threads finds a good match, you turn a global bool flag and stop all threads.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there any article or tutorial so I can learn and implement your comment accordingly?

Comment: I'm afraid, searching for the seeds for each thread is problem specific :/ Then it's just a while loop with an atomic variable for the flag, set to `_hash.substr(0, difficulty) == str.

Comment: Please see above, I added something. Thanks.

Comment: If you have a `single`, then it's not parallel. No, do a `while(not_found)` in parallel, each thread with its local `hash`, and if there is a result, update `not_found`.

Comment: This is what I did. May I request you to implement what you said about while(not_found). Thanks.

 #pragma omp parallel      
 {
  #pragma omp single      
  while (_hash.substr(0, difficulty) != str) {
   #pragma omp task     
   {
    ++_nonce;
    _hash = calculate_hash();
   }
  }
 }

Comment: I added above properly so you can amend. Thanks.

Comment: You still have the same while loop. That **cannot** work. `hash` is local to each thread, here you are only doing one at a time. Use several seeds for several `hash` and run each of them in a thread.

Comment: I am unsuccessful, if it's okay for you to implement, I will be grateful. Thanks.